# Can't find temp table in Redshift after Lambda loader times-out

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I've got a lambda function that does the followings

```
create table xyz
copy xyz from S3
```

The copy command runs longer than 5 minutes, and lambda times out after 5 minutes. 
What do we expect to see it Redshift after the COPY finishes.

I expected to see the temp table and all the rows from S3 files are in the xyz table, but I didn't see the temp table at all. Is this a correct behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, temp table is visible only within the session where it is created, and dropped when the connection is closed. This is a common database behavior. You can create temp tables with the same name at the same time from different connections and there will be no name collision. In your case it's better to create a regular table and then drop it when needed.

UPD: I don't know how your lambda is set. There's a high chance that if you don't see even the empty table the sql code runs in a transaction, so the whole thing is rolled back. If the function times out you still won't see the table populated because the connection dies. Probably the problem is not in your lambda but in your copy set up because 5+ min copy is very strange for Redshift. What's the file size and what's the cluster configuration? You might try to put too large file into multiple node cluster without breaking it to chunks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say a table instead of temp. I understood the behaviour of the temp table. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Alex, this is more for me to understand the behaviour what happens if Redshift is in the middle of executing queries when Lambda times out. The code was not run in a transaction eg no BEGIN or END. I want to understand this behaviour to address our current problem that is we have multiple COPYs in separate lambdas competing for transactions on the same destination table for the complete process of COPY into a table, delete from destination table where record exists in this new table, insert from this new table to destination table and drop the temporary staging table.